# Change ItemTemplate

Tags: c#

I have the following 2 DataTemplates:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemPhoto">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="{Binding Thumbail}" Height="80" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemAlbum">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="{Binding Thumbail}" Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

And 1 GridView

```
<GridView Grid.Row="1" Name="lstFlickrControl" 
                       SelectionMode="Multiple" 
                       ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemPhoto}"
                       ItemClick="lstFlickrControl_ItemClick" Holding="lstFlickrControl_Holding">
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
</GridView>
```

I want that when I click the photo menu GridView it should load the ItemPhoto DataTemple but when I click the albums menu GridView it should load the ItemAlbums DataTemple. Can someone please make some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, for example upon albums menu clicked change `ItemTemplate` to use `ItemAlbum` `DataTemplate` :

```
lstFlickrControl.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["ItemAlbum"];
```

note : you may need to change `this` in above sample to whatever UI control where you define those `DataTemplate`s